# How do I open fonts I've been sent which are showing up as 'exec' files?

Tags: macos, fonts, exec

This question is regarding to InDesign and fonts:

I just received a zip with fonts from a client, but unfortunately they are all exec files (whatever that is) and I can't open them.

What should I do to open them?

Answer (score 1):

## Why are these font files showing up as `exec` files?

So you were sent some fonts to work with an InDesign file, and what you ended up with is something like this:

[image: exec]

<sup>*(credit: [[Jongware]](https://forums.adobe.com/people/%5BJongware%5D) on the Adobe forums)*</sup>

Somewhere along the way the font files have been altered such that they aren't recognised as font files any more. This is a [common problem](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=font+file+exec). There's a suggestion that this may be [due to resource fork](https://discussions.apple.com/message/3407756#message3407756) issues.

### What should I do?

Ask your client to send you the files again:

> You may have to walk your client through zipping a file or turning on the Finder's "Show All Extensions" preference.

You said that you already received the files in a `zip` file; it may be worth double-checking that process to make sure they are being zipped correctly.